# Intellij dosen't show "bin" folder in ActionScript project

Tags: actionscript-3, intellij-idea

I got an issue with Intellij 11. It doesn't show the "bin" folder (ActionScript 3 project) in my project view on the left.

Under "Project Settings->Modules", "bin" is an "Excluded" folder, but there is no option to change this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to click on the `Excluded` button in the `Project Structure - Modules` tree explorer.

EDIT:

I see, the problem is perhaps that IntelliJ excludes by default the compiler output folder. Try changing the output folder in the `Project Structure - Project - Complier Output` text box.

I suspect you won't be able to change this behaviour though.

Comment: I tried it, but does not work. Just after a second, automatically IntelliJ puts the folder as "exclude".

Comment: I have done something different. I created a folder called "web-source" with all the files (index.html, data.xml...) and I've marked it as "Source". This way I can edit and then IntelliJ at compile time copy those files to the "bin" folder. Thanks for you help!